# Preencher formulário com python/ selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Estou tentando preencher um formulário com python/selenium mas não consigo encontrar o elemento para enviar o texto. Não consigo listar o form todo, é privado...

Formulário:

```
<td class="ml-FldCnt lo_22565 ml-BrdBottom" colspan="4" style="width:85%;">
<span id="master_DefaultContent_rts_ts3850_s3851_f18613c_wrapper" class="riSingle RadInput RadInput_archer autoWidth" style="width:100%;">
<input id="master_DefaultContent_rts_ts3850_s3851_f18613c" name="master$DefaultContent$rts$ts3850$s3851$f18613c" size="20" class="riTextBox riEnabled" aria-labelledby="loitem22565" type="text" value="">
<input id="master_DefaultContent_rts_ts3850_s3851_f18613c_ClientState" name="master_DefaultContent_rts_ts3850_s3851_f18613c_ClientState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="{&quot;enabled&quot;:true,&quot;emptyMessage&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;validationText&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;valueAsString&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;lastSetTextBoxValue&quot;:&quot;&quot;}"></span>
</td>
```

Já utilizei diversos códigos para localizar o campo de input e jogar o text dentro, mas nada funcionou..

Abaixo o último código que tentei:

```
titulo = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*@id="master_DefaultContent_rts_ts3850_s3851_f18613c"]')
titulo.clear()
titulo.send_keys(self.titulo_sol)
titulo.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
sleep(10)
```

Resultado:

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="master_DefaultContent_rts_ts3850_s3851_f18613c"]"}

Alguém conhece um jeito de acessar o campo input?

Obrigado.

Comment: Vc tentou o `find_element_by_id`?

Comment: já sim.obrigado. essa página tem javascript. acho que algo dele interfere  na pesquisa.Num teste rápido, quando passo o cursor do mouse no campo titulo, uma propriedade muda de situação. o class="riTextBox riEnabled" muda pra class="riTextBox riEnabled riHover".

Comment: Pessoal, encontrei uma forma: self.driver.switch_to.frame("record-1093-iframeEl"). dei foco no frame onde o input está e deu certo. encontrou o input e preenchi o seu conteúdo corretamente. obrigado a todos.